# jQuery every second div / nth-child

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have following **dynamic** DOM (so the user can add new div´s like post´s) and I want every second "div" with another background-color.
How can I put this with jquery?

```
<div>1
  <div>2
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6DGh/ and that could theoretically run infinitely

Comment: Is your suggestion that this could nest infinitely?

Comment: So in this example, which ones should have what background colour?

Comment: I know it might sound stupid but provide a fiddle where people can work on it. You will get faster answers

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: What means evey second divs? Could you provide a more complete HTML code to let us see what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y6DGh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fine:

```
$("div:odd").css("background","red");
$("div:even").css("background","blue");
```

You need to run this after you add a new element, which can result in a "blinking" effect...
Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/jnkLz/

Comment: I've added a fiddle and it works quite well with both of them

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how you see this but you can do something like :

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">1
  <div>2
    <div class="colorParents">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    display:block;
}

div.parent{
    background-color:red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$.each($('.colorParents').parentsUntil('.parent').addBack(), function (i) {
    if (i % 2) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/EtBCw/